# Как генерируется хэш-сумма для директорий?

Tags: python, python-3.x, хеширование, hashlib

Я пытаюсь посчитать хэш-сумма также, как это делается в 7z и многих других программах. 
В исходном коде 7z я не смог найти как это делается. Из других ответов я нашел что-то в этом стиле:

```py
fileHash = hashlib.sha256()
blocksize = 65536

with open(path,'rb') as f:
        f = f.read(blocksize)
        while f:
                fileHash.update(f)
                f = f.read(blocksize)
```

Данный код выполняется корректно. Я пытался переделать, но ничего не вышло.

Меня интересует именно хэш-сумма данных в файле (всех файлов в директории, единая хэш-сумма).

Comment: хеш директории по сути от хеша данных не отличается. просто в качестве данных используется отсортированный список файлов с их хешами

Comment: @Mike как мне единый хэш получить? Который при этом может человек сверить, например, через 7z. Я пробовал через список, не получалось.

Comment: Что бы сверить через 7z надо посмотреть как точно он формируется в 7z. А вообще подозреваю, что это может быть организовано по своему в каждом конкретном виде архивов

Comment: Какой именно хеш вы пытаетесь получить? Тот что показывается при "контекстное меню - CRC SHA - SHA-256"? Там 2 хеша, файлы, и файлы + имена

Comment: @Zergatul "хэш-сумма данных в файле". Да, файлов, меня интересует данный вариант, но если кто-либо может описать и все остальное, то я буду только рад. И именно директории, не файлов по отдельности.

Comment: Я нашел в исходниках кусок этого кода, он выглядит очень необычно, какие-то суммы хешей, какие-то нулевые массивы добавляют: https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip/blob/fabc2d1d468c61ac8e3adee752580519fc8bb91d/CPP/7zip/UI/Common/HashCalc.cpp#L141

Comment: @Zergatul да, я тоже это видел, но разобраться в этом для меня будет туго. Но видимо ответ придется искать самостоятельно)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сначала считать хэш каждого файла внутри директории, затем соединить все хэши в одну строку и выполнить хэш этой строки.

Пример:

```
import hashlib
from os import listdir

dir_hash = ''
for f in listdir('files'):
    with open('files/'+f, "rb") as f:
        file_hash = hashlib.sha256()
        while chunk := f.read(8192):
            file_hash.update(chunk)
    
    dir_hash += file_hash.hexdigest()

print(hashlib.sha256(dir_hash.encode('utf8')).hexdigest())
```

Я когда-то применял данный метод для определения изменений в директории.
Сразу могу сказать, этот метод является медленным для больших директорий.